# extract only ids from a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, underscore.js

I only need the ids of all documents in a collection in mongodb. I am using meteor. For now, I am using the basic ._each loop but I bet a better way exists but unfortunately its not clicking to me.

Below is my code :

```
var followedIds = Doubts.find({ch : chId, userId : userId}).fetch();
    var d_ids = [];
    _.each(followedIds, function(doubt){
        d_ids.push(doubt._id)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [_.pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) if you only need the ids.

Answer (score 2):

A small change in [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) can help you to fetch only _ids from collection:

```
var followedIds = Doubts.find({ch : chId, userId : userId},
      { 
           fields:{
                 _id:1
           }
      }).fetch();
    var d_ids = [];
    _.each(followedIds, function(doubt){
        d_ids.push(doubt._id)
    });
```

Comment: I tried the same already but got the full collection as output. I tried : var followedDoubtIds = Doubts.find({ch : chId, userId : userId}, {_id : 1}).fetch(); 
 console.log(followedDoubtIds).    It prints the whole document though

Comment: you need to wrap that in object, check the updated answer. Check this doc:https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/mongodb-queries-and-projections#tmc-the-mongodb-projection-document

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection_name.find({},{"id":1})
```

[See Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

**{}** means all documents

**{"id":1}** We are only interested in id not other fields.

Comment: I have a long document. I have 16 fields in the document. Would writing field_1 : 0 ..... field_16 : 0 be a good design?